# Dual OS running problem. Ubuntu is ok but windows 7 carsh down

Tags: system-installation

I have installed ubuntu 14.04LTS besides windows 7 ultimate after made a separate partition for ubuntu. Generally i intend to boot windows and ubuntu running together. I followed up all installation process step by step. I faced problem when i want to boot window 7. it says," an error occurred" please insert a disk. I have fresh windows disk and try to repair windows. But its unable to repair my windows. I don't have second option of backup restore because when i installed ubuntu i didn't take any backup. Please give me a right way solution. I do not want to reinstall windows. What i have now want to modify.Besides also want to running ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons why a Windows partition is not recognized. I'm assuming that your Ubuntu partition works fine since you haven't said anything otherwise.

Although this question is rather Windows-related, here are some things you could try. Please try them in the order they're given.

- Rebuild your MBR partition tables and check your entire disk for errors using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).
- Create a Windows Repair Disk. You'll find many in torrents. The disk includes just about everything you need to recover Windows.
- In case neither of these work, I suggest you backup everything you have and do a fresh install of Windows.